# Google Assistant Custom Commands | Hey Google, Open My App's page

Tags: android, voice-recognition, google-assistant-sdk

I want to open my android app's specific page with voice control in google assistant.

I read some article ["app actions"](https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/) can help when it released.

But **Vodafone** has already doing this feature.

In google assistant I can tell:

**For example:**

++ Hey Google, Open Vodafone my invoice

-- Vodafone's mobile app is opened and direct related pages.

I want to do it for **my custom application** . Hey Google, Open My Wonderful app and Book a hotel reservation and it will open my wonderful app's hotel reservation page

Is that restricted for us? Or can we do it programatically or non-programatically ..

I saw it just indicated commands is avaible. For example set alarm I will say to assistant and Mobile app will suggest me to related app. I don't want to do this. I want to create custom commands for my mobile application.

Comment: I joined a conferences about android, They told me that Yes I can. I will investigate google assistant sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Google I/O 2019, some updates were posted about App Actions:

- [Official documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/app/)
- [Google I/O 2019 session on App Actions (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQALSeGy9aY)
- [Sample application on github](https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin)

This kind of integration will be possible using these updates via the "[Open app feature](https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/bii-integrations#open_app_feature)" action. For example "Hey Google, open ***history*** on ***my app***" could let you open the history screen in "my app". That said, for specific use-cases, like travel booking, it's best to wait for the built-in Assistant intents to be supported for the travel vertical which will allow more powerful integrations such as "Hey Google, book a hotel in Paris on May 8 with ***my hotel app***".

Note that as of Google I/O 2019, App Actions is available for developers to start building but not available to end-users yet.