# How to define specific keywords to open the app from the google assistant without saying app name by using shortcuts.xml in android?

Tags: android, google-assistant, android-static-shortcuts

I want to open my application to its launcher screen by speaking a specific keyword[which is not app name]. According to [Android shortcuts for Assistant | Session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMs7DgniUqs&t=462s) (please check from duration 7:10 mins), this is achievable but I am not able to find any other document or demo for the same.

Please help me if anyone has any idea for the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The video refers to: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts#static

Comment: In the document, it is mentioned that we need to use BIIs for the same. Which means we need to use the full phrase with the app name. What we need to implement is a custom keyword without the app name. Can you please guide me here?@MorrisonChang

Comment: I believe using a phrase without the app name is a Beta feature of Google Assistant. As any app can have similar shortcuts, e.g. two food apps, it is up to the personalization features of Asst. to know that the user usually means "App" rather than "OtherApp". From https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/overview `Note: App Actions, like all Actions that support built-in intents, trigger on a number of factors, including quality and relevancy to the user's request. Based on those factors, Google may exercise discretion in surfacing your Action in response to user requests.`

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @MorrisonChang. Here I want to implement the same beta feature of Google Assistant but I am not sure where to add that keyword in the shortcut.xml file as it is providing only the phrasing for BIIs. A little guidance here will help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55530248/google-assistant-custom-commands-hey-google-open-my-apps-page